# Python error - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, relative-import

So, my files/folders structure is the following:

```
project/
├─ utils/
│  ├─ module.py
├─ server/
│  ├─ main.py
```

Inside `project/server/main.py` I'm trying to import `project/utils/module.py` using this syntax: `from ..utils.module import my_function`.

I'm using VSCode, and it even autocomplete for me as I type the module path. But when I run the file `project/server/main.py`, I get the error in the title.

I've read dozens of answers here on stack overflow about this topic but none of them used an example like this.

Comment: if your project is more than a single file, it's generally saner to run `python -m your.main.module` rather than `python your/main/module.py`, so that `sys.path` is used to find the main module, rather than defined based on the main module.

Comment: Add `__init__.py` in the subdirectories and set PYTHONPATH=<projectdir>

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is a [reference](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent) that explains this problem well. Basically, the problem is that `__package__` is not set when running standalone scripts.

**File structure**

```
.
└── project
    ├── server
    │   └── main.py
    └── utils
        └── module.py
```

**project/server/main.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__package__)
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 project/server/main.py
None
```

As we can see, the value of `__package__` is `None`. This is a problem because it is the basis of relative imports as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__):

> **`__package__`**
>
> ... This attribute is used instead of `__name__` to calculate **explicit relative imports** for main modules, as defined in PEP 366...

Where [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/#proposed-change) explains this further:

> The major proposed change is the introduction of a new module level attribute, `__package__`. When it is present, **relative imports will be based on this attribute** rather than the module `__name__` attribute.

To resolve this, you can run it as a module via [-m flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) instead of a standalone script.

**Output**

```
$ python3 -m project.server.main  # This can be <python3 -m project.server> if the file was named project/server/__main__.py
project.server
```

**project/server/main.py**

```
from ..utils.module import my_function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__package__)
    print("Main")
    my_function()
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 -m project.server.main
project.server
Main
My function
```

Now, `__package__` is set, which means it can now resolve the explicit relative imports as documented above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try without using `from ..util.module import my_function` rather try direct `import my_function`.

If it doesn't work you need to create a new file which can be empty named as `__init__.py` under both `utils` folder and `server` folder. `__init__.py` creates an actual module that can be called for any module.

Comment: I verify creating `__init__.py` on both callee and caller module did not work for me.