# Relative import in python: using -m flag not working unless moving up parent directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have replicated the scenario in this exact question:

[Python error - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960171/python-error-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-packa)

However, the answer for me does not work. I'm running python3 (3.7.9) in VSCode with the following file structure:

```
project/
├─ utils/
│  ├─ module.py
├─ server/
│  ├─ main.py
```

When in the directory `all_projects/project/server/`:

Running `python3 main.py` I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Running `python3 -m main`: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

-

When in the directory `all_projects/project/`:

Running `python3 -m server.main`: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

-

ONLY when in the directory `all_projects/`:

Running `python3 -m project.server.main`: works as expected.

What the hell is going on here? Why does `python3 -m server.main` not work in the `project` directory?

Answer (score 0):

it could be anything ! including permissions!
but you should use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I am using a virtual environment in the project folder