# import function from another folder's file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, importerror, relative-import

My project directory looks like this:

```
project/
├─ new/
│  ├─ test.py
├─ docs.py
├─ main.py
```

Within my main.py, I import a function from `docs.py`like this:

```
from docs import get_my_conn
```

and it works fine.

How can I import the same thing within `new/test.py` as well? I tried:

```
from ..docs import get_my_conn
```

but I get this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960171/python-error-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-packa

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is initialize the `new` directory as a package. In order to do this, inside the `new` directory make an empty file titled `__init__.py`. After you do this, go back to your `main.py` code and import it like this instead:

```
from new.test import (function)
```

Your new tree should look like this:

```
project/
├─ new/
│  ├─ test.py
|  ├─ __init__.py
├─ docs.py
├─ main.py
```

P.S.
If you are trying to import a function from docs.py into test.py, you probably should not do this. This is because it will result in an error known as a circular import. This will cause your script to no longer work. If you want to import a function from `docs.py` into `test.py` then put them in the same directory (or directory at the same level of the project hierarchy).

Comment: I want to import a function from docs.py into test.py. Not the other way around

Comment: Yes, I am aware. Please refer to the PostScript. I explained that it would probably lead to a circular import error.

Comment: is there any other way of achieving it? without putting them in the same directory? Like using an __init__.py script as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: You can achieve it with __init__.py but in the long run, it's not a good idea. As your code structure starts to get more complicated, you'll end up importing things that depend on each other. You can refer to this [link](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-circular-import/) on circular import errors to learn more about them.

Comment: so are there any other alternatives??? also I didn't achieve it with init.py either. pls see my comment under the other answer

Comment: The link I posted goes over alternatives.

Comment: If you followed the steps correctly, you should be able to access it using `from docs.py import (function)`. If that doesn't work I would probably need to see your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in how you are running your code - you should add the init files as in

```
project/
├─ new/
│  ├─ test.py
   ├─ __init__.py
├─ docs.py
├─ main.py
```

then run your code as

```
python -m new.test # note no py
```

from the `project` folder.

Comment: why is the init folder inside new? I want to import a function from docs into new/test.py. Not the other way around. Shouldnt init.py be on the same level as docs

Comment: nope, it didn't