# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, importerror, relative-import

I have a folder like this:

```
draft
    model
        a.py
    package
        b.py
```

I want to import a function inside a.py into b.py by this code `from ..model import a`.
But I got an error like this:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I try the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960171/python-error-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-packa)
`python -m package.b`
But another error occur:
`ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

I have try to add `__init__.py` to both model and package, and draft folder, too.
But the same error still happened.

I know that there's a solution like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(f'{source_path}/draft/model')
```

But when i move this code to another computer, the source_path must be changed. It may occur error when i forget.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-can-i-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: What is the import and from which directory did you run `python -m package.b`?

Comment: I write this code inside the b.py `from ..model import a`. And I run python -m package.b in folder draft

Comment: This seems correct - do add the `__init__.py` files they are needed and make sure you run from the draft folder - if it still errors out please post me the traceback